# How to cut a straight 10cm section out of a 20cm post

Tags: wood, cut

I want to cut a cuboid section out of a 20cm post.

[image: hand saw shows where I want to cut straight down]

My only thought is to make lots of cuts and then go to work with a chisel.

Are there any alternatives?

Update...

Went as far as I dared with a chainsaw
[image]

And then used a chisel
[image]

But I still think this is a worthwhile post.  Maybe there is still a better way?

That was a test - the real ones are oak

Thank you to everyone for contributing.

Comment: Only a partial assist, hence a comment and not an answer. Make a pair of diagonal cuts to remove the bulk of the material before proceeding with your choice of final removal. Also, a smaller saw will allow you to cut on the ninety degree line after a minimal amount of chisel work.

Comment: Do you have a circular saw? If you feel competent, you could plunge along your lines and have most of the work done for you.

Comment: What tools do you have available? How good does the interior surface have to be? Obviously you're already aware of the method you describe, and have the tools with which it can be done, and that **is** one of the standard ways to do this (in fact possibly the best method in most cases for most people, since it's simple, direct and doable with variable tool sets).

Comment: I have pretty much every type of saw but I can't see any easy way to do this. I need to make quite a few of these cuts (the picture is just an illustration of the type of cut) Think I'll just have to go manual on this one. Thinking of using a circular saw to make lots of initial cuts.

Comment: *"but I can't see any easy way to do this"* The method you described **is** an easy way to do this, arguably **the** easy way :-) Prior to the development of this specific version of the basic method (I believe arising from the effortless and far faster cuts a power saw allows) most workers would have removed the bulk of the material by a more labour-intensive use of the chisel to chop out the waste. You could still do it this way if you have a strong wide chisel, a heavy mallet or hammer, would prefer to do fewer (or zero) intermediate saw cuts and would like to just set to on the job [contd]

Comment: ...I realise that if you're not used to it the number of them and the total effort involved might seem daunting but just get going and I'm sure before you know it you'll be half done. An alternative wrinkle that might help this seem less effortful (even though the total expenditure is the same) is to adopt a production-line approach, instead of doing each notch separately to completion you do all of one operation. BTW although the pieces are heavy clamping the wood down firmly so it can't move could help work go more smoothly, it usually does in any scenario where a workpiece can shift about.

Answer (score 5):

When I have made similar removal of wood I use my skill saw and make a LOT of parallel cuts so it is easy to clean out with a chisel, 10cm is a bit more than my skill saw could handle, however, I would still set it as deep as possible, make the cuts and then use a different saw to finish making as deep as I needed.

Comment: I'd add that drilling can also remove wood, in this instance of such depth of removal not sure which would be best

Comment: Maybe an oscillating saw (for rough, initial removal)

Comment: @depperm, a saw blade in an oscillating tool would certainly work, but a chisel should be faster. Significantly faster in fact once the initial vertical cuts are done.